# React Native: Variable state not updated on first click

Tags: react-native, react-android

I am new in react-native and i am working on an app.

The below code is a simple react-native app which has a custom component with custom events.

But the problem is the variable state is not updated on the first click on the component. But when i click on the second item, The state of the variable is updated.

Please find the code and screenshot below.

**App.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, SafeAreaView, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';
import Dropdown from './components/dropdown';

const app = () => {
    const [ itemData, setItemData ] = useState('');

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ margin: 50 }}>
            <Dropdown 
              onPressItems={(item) => {
                  ToastAndroid.show('item: ' + item, ToastAndroid.LONG)
                  setItemData(item)
                  ToastAndroid.show('setItem: ' + itemData, ToastAndroid.LONG)
              }}/>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default app;
```

**Dropdown.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

const Dropdown = (props) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { props.onPressItems('this is sample data') }}>
            <Text>Sample Text</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
} 

export default Dropdown;
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

**Code:** https://snack.expo.dev/@likithsai/custom-component

Please help me on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState()` hook changes the state asynchronously. so you can't make sure that the state will be changed immediately after calling `setItemData()` function.

Try `useEffect` to run a side effect whenever the state changes.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  ToastAndroid.show("setItem: " + itemData, ToastAndroid.LONG);
}, [itemData]);
```

However, this code will show the toast on the component mount. to prevent it try something like this:

```js
const isInitialMount = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isInitialMount.current) {
    isInitialMount.current = false;
  } else {
    ToastAndroid.show("setItem: " + itemData, ToastAndroid.LONG);
  }
}, [itemData]);
```

Comment: Ok. What can i do for this issue. :(

Comment: Updated @likithsai

Comment: is it possible to setItemData(itemData) inside the useEffect()?. I know its a silly question, but i actually want to store the value inside a variable.

Comment: of course, you can. However in the example provided above you don't need

Comment: Just update your `onPressItems` callback to ```js (item) => {
                  ToastAndroid.show('item: ' + item, ToastAndroid.LONG)
                  setItemData(item)
              }```

Comment: Can you update the answer with setItem function. I have tried this solution and it doesnt work. https://snack.expo.dev/@likithsai/custom-component

Comment: @likithsai https://snack.expo.dev/@yamankatby/custom-component I have replaced `ToastAndroid` with `alert` because it doesn't work on the web and I'm trying on the web.

Comment: Wow. You are a saviour Man. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working just as expected. One of the hooks that are useful to watch for state updates is `useEffect`. You can add this to your code and see it's working properly:

```
const app = () => {
    const [ itemData, setItemData ] = useState('');

    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log('updated itemData:', itemData)
    }, [itemData])

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ margin: 50 }}>
            <Dropdown 
              onPressItems={(item) => {
                  ToastAndroid.show('item: ' + item, ToastAndroid.LONG)
                  setItemData(item)
                  ToastAndroid.show('setItem: ' + itemData, ToastAndroid.LONG)
              }}/>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

You need to take into consideration that `useState` updates are asynchronous, which means the change won't be reflected immediately.

Comment: OK. Can i use setItemData(itemData) inside the useEffect()?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you are trying to do. If you dependency array in your `useEffect` includes `itemData` it won't make any sense since it will create a loop. What you can do is to show the Toast inside the `useEffect` to show the correct data.